# Call C++ code from c#

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I am implementing a GUI in WPF C# (Visual Studio 2008) for a mathematical model written in c++. I have full access to the source code of both projects in a single VS solution

My question is:

1. is it possible to call from C# a method in C++ ?
2. If yes, what is the best option?
3. What I need to do in c++ to "expose" the method?

I have tried to "Add Reference", but I dont think it is going to work like this.

Comment: It's called Interop.  That term should help you in your Google searches.  You can do C-style declaration interop, or COM object interop.  This should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various options.

The simplest option is often to create a wrapper to the C++ methods you need using C++/CLI.  You could then add a reference to the C++ DLL from within the C# project, and use it normally.

Alternatively, you can expose the C++ methods you need via a C API, then use P/Invoke to call them from C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++ library (.dll), you can use it in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("filename.dll")]
public static extern void MethodName(ParameterList);
```

Then you can call `MethodName(...)` in your C# code.

Comment: Note that this requires `MethodName` to be exported as a C style method (ie: using `extern "C"` in the declaration) so it's name doesn't get C++ name mangling.