# How can I call my c++ program in c# gui?

Tags: c#, c++

Can I call this c++ code in c# gui? If so, how could I do this?
My c++ function:

```
int getSize(const char *file) {
    HANDLE hFile;

    LPCWSTR inFile = (LPCWSTR)file;
    hFile = CreateFile(
        inFile,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );

    DWORD dwFileSize;
    dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return dwFileSize;
}
```

I would like to use it in c# like this:

```
int fileSize = getSize(DecryptionOpenFile.FileName);
```

Comment: You might find this useful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx

Comment: P/Invoke. Make a **C** exported function and import in your C# program using DllImport. Otherwise...well compile C++ code using C++/CLI and make a thin manager wrapper around it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call C++ code from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620845/call-c-code-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Casting `const char*` to `const wchar_t*` is 99% likely not what you want. You most likely need an actual conversion of characters from one encoding to the other. Although if you're limiting yourself to Microsoft's ANSI beforehand, you can simply use the ANSI version of `CreateFile`, knowing that it disallows most filename characters.

Comment: As an aside, there's a C# method to get the size of a file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b555eac9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import your DLL into your C# GUI project and make a wrapper around it.

Here is a sample :

```
public static class IncDll
{
    [DllImport("myLibrary.dll")]
    public static extern void MethodName(ParameterList);
}
```

Then in your code, you just need to call it like this :

```
IncDll.MethodName(params);
```

You can also have two projects, one in C++/CLI and another one in C#.

The C++/CLI is wrapping native C++ API.

Then add reference to C++/CLI library into C# and you will be able to use native library through the wrapper.